# array of character in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a question simple like that: Let user enter some words from keyboard,one word per line until a '.' (period) entered then print out result, for example:

```
Enter a word: word1
Enter a word: word2
Enter a word: .
You have entered 2 word(s):
word1
word2
```

OK here my try but when I run it said file has stopped working after let me enter first word

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () 
{ 
    char *word[50]; //each word has maximum 49 character
    int i=0, number_of_word;

    do
    {
        printf ("Enter a word: ");
        scanf("%s", &word[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while (word[i][0]!='.');

    number_of_word =i;
    printf ("You entered %d word(s):\n", number_of_word);
    for (i=0; i<number_of_word; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", &word[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------**

EDIT 1:

OK I try this, it worked but I am still looking for best way to declare an unknown size array of character string since I don't know neither how many word user may enter nor how many letter of each word, in C++ it may called dynamic allocation array, I have no idea how to do it in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () 
{ 
    char word[20][50]; //array has maximum 20 words, each word maximum 50 character
    int i=0, number_of_word;

    do
    {

        printf ("Enter a word: ");
        scanf("%s", word[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while (word[i-1][0]!='.');

    number_of_word =i-1;
    printf ("You entered %d word(s):\n", number_of_word);
    for (i=0; i<number_of_word; i++)
    {
       printf("Word %d is %s\n", i, word[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not assigning any memory to store the individual strings, so your program invokes **undefined behaviour**.

This:

```
char *word[50];
```

defines an array of 50 pointers, but no further storage.

And when you do this:

```
scanf("%s", &word[i]);
```

you're writing into the *pointer* array.

Comment: ok any suggestion how do I declare the array since I don't know  neither how many word user may enter nor how many letter of each word

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char *word[50]; //each word has maximum 50 word
    char enter_word[50];//maximum 49 character
    int i=0, number_of_word;

    while(1){
        printf("Enter a word: ");
        scanf("%49s", enter_word);
        if(*enter_word == '.')break;
        word[i++]=strdup(enter_word);
    }

    number_of_word = i;
    printf ("You entered %d word(s):\n", number_of_word);
    for (i=0; i<number_of_word; i++){
        printf("%s\n", word[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<number_of_word; ++i)
        free(word[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
char *word[50];
```

You have 50 char pointers pointing to random memory. What you want is something like this:

```
char word[50][50];
```

Note that you can have only 49 words (and the '.'), and each can have less than 50 characters (don't forget the \0, so a word with 50 chars will overflow).

And you will want to change your scanf call to something like:

```
scanf("%s", word[i]);
```

Note that you do not need the &, since word[i] is already a pointer.

Comment: if I do char word[50][50]; isn't this a 2-d array? How can I validate if user input '.'? is it: word[i][0]=='.' ?

Comment: @LongBodie Yes, it is a 2-d array. You can also say it is an array of arrays of chars or an array of strings (since a string is an array of chars). You can test the input as you were doing: word[i][0] == '.'. word[i] is the string i, word[i][0] is the first character of string i.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *word[50];
```

You have an array of 50 pointers. You want an array of 50 byte chunks. How many words do you want to read? If you know the maximum, you can allocate the space in advance. If you don't, you need something like a linked list of strings, to which you can append a new item when you read it.

Answer (score 0):

Its your printf Call. Remember to add the end character \0 to the end of the word. Printf when printing strings prints everything in the char array till it reads an end character \0

BasicAlly... Hos should printf know how long the word is and when it should stop printing?(Right now it continues forever)

Answer (score 0):

You've done nothing to allocate memory for the individual strings.

Char *word[50] just declares a pointer to *one* array of char pointers.

EDIT

I'll try to illustrate this here    with some pseudo code...formatted code on a phone is nearly impossible :) Given a prior char * input[50]:

```
char * nextString;

bool entering=true;

do{

nextString =calloc(50);

// enter the string to nextString

if (nextString[0] != '.'){

     input[i] = nextString;

     i++;

 } else{

 entering=false;

}
}
}while(entering)
```

Comment: ok any suggestion how do I declare the array since I don't know  neither how many word user may enter nor how many letter of each word

Comment: You're going to need to declare something with some limits beforehand, eg char [50][100] and add checks to avoid overrunning boundaries. Writing the chars directly into unallocated memory is trouble from the word go.

Comment: pls check my question again, I edited but still can not run properly

Comment: You're running your termination check on a string after you perform the increment on your index variable, so your input loop will never end. You didn't mention what your new error was, specifically...

Comment: My bad, it should be while (word[i-1][0]!='.'); |||||| I am still looking for best way to declare an unknown size array of character string, in C++ it may call dynamic allocation array, I have no idea how to do it in C

Comment: I personally would declare and allocate a local temp string (char pointer) inside the loop, use it to receive each new value, then set that index pointer to the address of the allocated temporary string. I would be happy to post a sample but answering on a phone and typing is at best a challenge. The idea I'm suggesting here does the allocation here at the input level rather than at application start time...

Answer (score 0):

"char *word[50]" have done nothing to allocate the memory for the individual string.
you should allocate it by using the function of alloc

Answer (score 0):

you just try to use "%[^\n]" place of "%s" in scanf().

because "%s" stores characters until it found first space in the string.

try this with your very first asked Program

May its help to you.